# Quero exibir uma imagem que eu cadastrei no banco de dados

Tags: php, upload

```
<?php 
   $result = ExibirDados();
     while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><img <?php echo "src=upload/".$resultado.">"; ?> </td>
                <td> 
  <?php } ?>
```

fica dando esse erro  Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConstrutoresFree\Dozero\index.php on line 150
src=upload/Array>

Comment: Não seria `$resultado["nome_do_campo_imagem_na_tabela"]` ?

Comment: correto, obrigado deu certo !